# Add # To URL Redirect?

Tags: html, url, redirect, web

So I am making a test website just for practice and right now the website is accessible by clicking [here](http://abyssaltest.hol.es). My first question is can I get the http:// to appear in the URL along with www? My second question is instead of having http://www.abyssaltest.hol.es/, I want it to be http://www.abyssaltest.hol.es/#/ and when it redirects to another page to be http://www.abyssaltest.hol.es/#/test. Is there anyway I can make either of these possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both things can be acomplished with **apache's rewrite engine**, however, to explicitly answer your question you might want to give some more information on your server configuration (i.e. are you using an online-server or do you work on a local ('usual') HTML-file? If on a server-> Apache? Microsoft?).

If you try to archieve this with bare HTML (or CSS / JS) it is not possible. Or at least I cannot imagine how to accomplish it, maybe javascript can help you to find a workaround, but this is unlikely plus it would only *appear* to be that "new" URL instead of *actually* sending the HTTP request to that destination.

Clearify your goal (e.g. what do you need this functionality for?) and I am sure there are many people willing to find a solution together ! Meanwhile, check out [this article on .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules). (Especially the second example should be of use).

So long - happy coding!

Comment: No I'm using Windows 10 so I prefer not to use an Apache Server only for the sole reason that I don't know how to make an Apache Server public with a domain instead of just local. So I am using custom HTML and PHP and am uploading files to a simple free hosting service just to test it out.

Comment: Within your (remote server's) root directory there should be a file called .htaccess. To archieve your goal, you'll have to manipulate it's content (back it up before you get fancy with it). The link I provided explains how to do both. In this case, as you are using a remote (free hosting) service, your local operating system does not make a difference. Most likely, they support mod_rewrite and you should be able to work yourself through! Best of luck. It looks more complicated than it actually is, so don't give up if it takes a few tries.